# How to get actual localization/lang in golang?

Tags: go, localization, lang

There is function who return localize/lang in golang ? 
Something like HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in PHP

I wanted to make a dynamically changing language page but i can't find this.

Comment: Check out this blog post: [Language and Locale Matching in Go](https://blog.golang.org/matchlang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.Header.Get("Accept-Language")` is what you are looking for.

The function will return something like: `en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6`

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index) 
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error happend", err)
    }
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {        
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        fmt.Println(r.Header.Get("Accept-Language"))
    }
}
```

And the corresponding `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` php function will return the same information: `en-US,en;q=0.5`.